# SST Python not waiting for page to load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sst

I have set `set_wait_timeout(60.0)` and use the `wait_for` in my code; however, the code is moving too fast and not allowing for the page to load, even with using `add_timestamp=True`. Is there any other way to get the code to wait longer for the page to load before moving to the next step? Below is my code:

```
__author__ = 'Brenda'

import unittest
from sst.actions import 
from sst import config

run_test('valid-login')
set_wait_timeout(60.0)
assert_link(get_element(text='View My Start Page'))
click_element(get_element(text='View My Start Page'),wait=True)
wait_for
take_screenshot('my-startpage.png',add_timestamp=True)
simulate_keys('white_border','BACK_SPACE')
wait_for(get_element(text='View My Start Page'))
assert_link(get_element(text='Make a Blog Entry'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

My expectation was that a `wait_for` would allow the page to load before moving to the next step. Any help on this? Thanks!

Below is the traceback for the error:
[image]

Comment: Please do not convert text into a graphic - it makes it invisible to search engines, and therefore less like to get indexed properly.

Comment: It won't let me copy and paste it and instead of typing it out, I made it into a graphic. I apologize, but that was my only option.

Comment: See this: https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_author__ = 'Brenda'

import unittest
from sst.actions import
from sst import config

run_test('valid-login')
set_wait_timeout(60.0)
assert_link(get_element(text='View My Start Page'))
click_element(get_element(text='View My Start Page'),wait=True)
wait_for(assert_title, 'new page title')
take_screenshot('my-startpage.png',add_timestamp=True)
simulate_keys('white_border','BACK_SPACE')
wait_for(assert_title, 'new page after navigation')
assert_link(get_element(text='Make a Blog Entry'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can  you give me an example of how that would actually look? My text elements don't have any id's. I'm sorry if I'm sounding naive on this, but I've only been working with Selenium for a month now.

Comment: I changed my statement to `wait_for(get_text(get_elements_by_css('#intro_w > div.welcome')),'Welcome ')` and now I receive the error message `AssertionError: Element with id: [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x034647F0>] does not exist.

Comment: Can you please tell me which line this is failing on?

Comment: Line 906 in sst\actions.py

Comment: Sorry Brenda not sure which line is that on your test code. Your test does not contain line number

Comment: Sorry. It fails on line 10, which is `wait_for(get_text(get_elements_by_css('#quick_c_ul > li:nth-child(1) > a')),'View My Start Page')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66507/discussion-between-saifur-and-brenda).